# getter for a static const variable to initialize a two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class ship
{
private:
    static const int num1 = 5;
    static const int num2 = 5;
protected:
    virtual int getNum1(){
        return num1;
    }
    int mainArray[getNum1()][num2];
}
```

basically I want to make a getter for a static const variable, this getter is later going to be used to initialize the array below it. how can i do this? (I am getting many errors with the current code above, it is just there to demonstrate my problem better). I want to be able to have a class that inherits from this class and change the size of the array using virtual getters.
 thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Impossible: array size should be known at compile time. Use dynamic memory allocation if it's not. More problems: 1) we tend to use library containers instead of plain arrays, 2) Most times you will not want to use multidimensional containers, but to use proper indexing on one-dimensional array instead 3) do you really need statics here? Looks like you are trying to write C with classes instead of C++. I would strongly recommend you to pick up a [C++ best practices book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before coding any further.

Comment: I might use dynamicly allocated arrays, they seem to be the solution now that I think about it. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your static const int public. As it is const noone can change it anyway and the compiler will understand...

```
class Ship
{
    public:
    static const int num2 = 5;
};
static float myArray[Ship::num2];
```

As it turned out in the comments section of the question, there is need to have flavours of ships which differ in the size of that internal array. Trying to override a virtual function to get the size, the array shall have won't work.
Here a template based version where those classes can still be used in a polymorphic way.

```
class IShip
{ virtual void Sink() = 0; // and so on. Anything those classes have in common...
};
template<int xDim, int yDim>
class SomeShip
    : public IShip
{
    static const int num1 = xDim;
    static const int num2 = yDim;
    int mainArray[xDim][yDim];
public:
   // Implementation of IShip...
};

typedef SomeShip<5,5> Ship;
typedef SomeShip<10,5> Bigship;

Bigship myBigShip;
void HandleShip( IShip * ship ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish what you want - with a getter initializing the array. Why don't you just use the `num1` there instead? Also, you can add the keyword `static` before `int getNum1()` - if you decide to keep that method anyway.

Comment: because I want to be able to have a class that inherits from this class and change the size of the array using virtual getters.

Comment: @MatiasChara Your compiler will not accept the return value from a getter to initialize an array like that. Alternative: Take a std::vector and use resize() instead.

Comment: the only issue is I would rather not use vector (I would have to change lots of code), is there any way to work around this issue?

Comment: Instead of doing it by inheritance, you could still do it with templates. Then some sugary typedefs. ``template<int num1, int num2> class WithSomeArray; typedef WithSomeArray<5,5> ship; typedef WithSomeArray<10,5> Bigship;``

Comment: I havent learned templates yet, I will learn them and then test out your idea. thanks for the reply and the comments! have a good day!